# How to create the dataframe using many lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have many lists(A1,A2) below:

```
   [    date,       open  , high,   low   ]

A1=['2015/11/26', 9861.48, 8484.9, 4656.74]

A2=['2015/11/27', 9841.48, 8384.9, 4256.74]
.
.
.
```

I want to create a dataframe using these lists and index is date.

How to create the dataframe and use for loop?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could i use for loop?

Comment: I have more than 3 lists, so Could anyone know how to use for loop to create dataframe.

Comment: How are you conatin you lists? Is it list of lists?

Comment: yes,[A1,A2,A3.......]

Comment: you could use @asadmshah answer but istead of [A1, A2] put your list of lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have list of lists than it's pretty easy:

```
colNames = ["date", "open", "high", "low"]
A1=['2015/11/26', 9861.48, 8484.9, 4656.74]
A2=['2015/11/27', 9841.48, 8384.9, 4256.74]
A3=['2015/11/28', 9801.48, 8284.9, 3856.74]
your_lists = [A1, A2, A3]
df = pd.DataFrame(your_lists, columns=colNames)
df = df.set_index('date')


In [436]: df
Out[436]:
               open    high      low
date
2015/11/26  9861.48  8484.9  4656.74
2015/11/27  9841.48  8384.9  4256.74
2015/11/28  9801.48  8284.9  3856.74
```

Comment: But I have more than 3 lists maybe 1000 lists

Comment: I can't define all of them. Thank you.

Comment: @easyway it's already defined as I understand. Could you show part of your list of lists, i.e. list_of_lists[:10]?

Answer (score 4):

If you have these variables:

```
colNames = ["date", "open", "high", "low"]
A1=['2015/11/26', 9861.48, 8484.9, 4656.74]
A2=['2015/11/27', 9841.48, 8384.9, 4256.74]
```

Then you can get the DataFrame and set the index like so:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([A1, A2], columns=colNames).set_index(colNames[0])
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your update, since your data is already a list of lists, eg:

```
dataset = [A1, A2, ..., AN]
```

Then you can build your DataFrame like this:

```
colNames = ["date", "open", "high", "low"]
df = pandas.DataFrame(dataset, columns=colNames).set_index(colNames[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([A1,A2])

df.columns = ['date','open','high','low']

df = df.set_index('date')
```

which returns:

```
               open    high      low
date                                
2015/11/26  9861.48  8484.9  4656.74
2015/11/26  9861.48  8484.9  4656.74
```

EDIT:

If you have more than two lists, you can build a List of Lists as:

```
L = [A1,A2,A3,A4,...,An]
```

and then pass it directly to the dataframe constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Comment: Thanks all of your answers.